# Is this an instance of personification or is it a simile?

Tags: grammar, analogy, figurative

I've been sometimes a little confused on how direct personification must be. For example, consider the following phrase used to describe a river:

> Like a snake it winds through the craggy mountainside.

Is that simply an analogy comparing a snake to a river, or is it an instance of personification/anthropomorphism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Personification* and *anthropomorphism* refer to representation of something as a **human being**.

In the presented sentence there's no mention of anything human; the noun phrases are *a snake* and *the craggy mountainside*.

Look for the human image before you suspect personification or anthropomorphism.

Comment: Ah, got it. That makes sense, a mistake on my end.

Answer (score 2):

- A metaphor is when you say something **is** something.
- Similes mean a something that is **like** another something.
- Personification is when you make a thing, idea, or an animal do
  something only a human can do.

In the phrase, "Like a snake it winds through the craggy mountainside," *like* is the giveaway; it's a simile.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if there were a counterpart of *personification* for living beings in general, that would have been what the OP intended to say.

Secondly, if the sentence was instead:

> it ***snakes*** through the craggy mountainside.

or even:

> it winds through the craggy mountainside, hissing now and then.

You know it is akin to *personification*.